# Subclassing a subclass of UIImageView - Forward declaration errors

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, subclassing

I have read question after question about people getting the same error as me, but I simply do not understand them, so before you go searching for duplicate questions, maybe someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong with this subclassing deal.

I have a subclass of UIImageView called `swapView` that I want to subclass to override the method `-(void)count` for special cases. I went to subclass this as I have any pre-existing UIKit class, but when I tried to build and run the project, I get this error:

```
Attempting to use the forward class 'swapView' as superclass of 'coinView'
```

**I have tried** putting both the `#import` statement of `swapView` and `@class swapView` in `coinView.h` and I've tried putting the import statement in `coinView.m`, but it refuses to build because of this continued error. If I move the import statement into the .m file, all references to the superclass's methods and properties, such as `@property (nonatomic) int max;` cause errors as well.

What am I doing wrong?

**swapView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface swapView : UIImageView
{
    NSTimer* tmr;
}

@property (nonatomic) int current;
@property (nonatomic) int max;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* firstImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* secondImage;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL smallMax;

@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController* pvc;

- (BOOL)testCollision:(CGPoint)point;
- (float)randomFloatBetween:(float)smallNumber bigNumber:(float)bigNumber;

@end
```

**coinView.h**

```
#import "swapView.h"

@class swapView;

@interface coinView : swapView

- (void)count;
- (void)move;

@end
```

Comment: How about remove @class swapView; in coinView.h?

Comment: Causes `Cannot find interface declaration for 'swapView', superclass of 'coinView'`

Comment: Are you sure you spelled everything correctly? I get no errors with your code if I import swapView.h (rather than using @class) into the coinView.h file. BTW, you should capitalize the names of your classes.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, but you should never have both `#import xxx.h` and `@class Xxx`! The whole purpose of `@class Xxx` is to say, "Trust me, Xxx is a class, but you don't need to know the details." If you `#import xxx.h`, where Xxx is declared as a class, then we know it's a class and we know the details.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I've spelled everything correctly. I've been able to get it to compile using tw_airball's method; I don't know why...and as for my capitalization, I learned to make classes the user interacts with capitalized and supporting classes lowercase on the first letter like method names, but IDK maybe my teacher was wrong.

Comment: the caps thing is just convention. makes it easier to read. The error was likely caused by `swapView.h` and not `coinView.h` -- the superclass was also both forward declaring and importing `ViewController.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inheritance, the superclass MUST be inherited.

**coinView.h**

```
#import "swapView.h"
@interface coinView : swapView
  - (void)count;
  - (void)move;
@end
```

You're both forward declaring and importing `ViewController.h` in your `swapView`, which may cause compiler to complain.

**swapView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController

@interface swapView : UIImageView
.
.
.
@end
```